# A control in NSTableCellView is being moved to right automatically after resizing or scrolling

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to implement a counter view that shows items count in NSTableCellView. 
The weird thing is it gets moved to right automatically after resizing window or scrolling the NSOutlineView which has the NSTableCellView.
Here is some screenshots of it. You will be able to see the counter view which shows "42" being moved to right after resize the window.

[image: The weird behavior]
Following is the init state of the counter view.
[image: Init State]
Following is the state after resize window.
[image: After Resize]
Following is difference between init position and the position after resize window.
[image: The Difference]
[image: Cell Autoresize Property]
Cell Autoresize Property
[image: Count Button Autoresize Property]
Count Button Autoresize Property

[image]
[image]

I'm guessing this is related to scrollview but I was not able to find more clues about this issue. BTW, official Mail App on Mac works as same with this but the difference is the counter of the Mail app is being changed right after launch so it does not being moved after resize window.

Anybody knows about this? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here is a link that allows you to download the sample project that apple provides and you can reproduce what I'm facing.
[Sidebar Demo App that providing by Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

You just need to change Deployment target before you run it from Project -> Targets -> Deployment Info section.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so, what are the restraints? It's obviously some aligning issue but without knowing how the alignments are specified, it's impossible to offer suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No, I'm not using autolayout. I'm using autoresizing property instead. I just hook up to right via Interface Builder.

Comment: I've attached 2 screenshots related to the Autoresize properties.

Comment: What are Column Sizing of the outline view and Resizing of the column? It looks like the column first has an inital width and then autoresizes.

Comment: @Willeke Column size is 210 and it's same with the TableCellView.

Comment: I mean "Column Sizing" and "Resizing" in the XIB or the `columnAutoresizingStyle` and `resizingMask` properties.

Comment: @Willeke Column is not view so it doesn't have any columnAutoresizingStyle and resizingMask both.

Comment: `columnAutoresizingStyle` is a property of `NSTableView`, the superclass of `NSOutlineView`. `resizingMask` is a property of `NSTableColumn`. In the XIB, does the table column (`NSTableColumn`) exactly fit inside the outline view?

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for your attention about this and I really appreciate it.
I've attached 2 more screenshots about autoresizing properties of NSOutlineView and NSTableColumn in it at the and of my question.
As you can see I can't find any autoresizing properties of NSTableColumn via Interface builder.

Comment: @Willeke I also left a link to download sample code about it. Apple provides sample Sidebar example and it also has same count moving problem what I'm having.

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? I can't reproduce the problem with the Sidebar Demo example on macOS 10.12.1 (Sierra). Also what are your system language and region settings (in System Preferences)?

Comment: @KenThomases Really? Wow! I'm still using "OS X Elcapitan 10.11.6" and the system language is English and the region is South Korea.
Wow! This is really useful information. I will try it again after my macOS upgrade to Sierra. Thank you very MUCH!!! YEAP!

Comment: The Sidebar Demo example works ok on OS X 10.10.

Comment: @Willeke You mean working well without counter moving to right issue? Right?

Comment: Yes, the counter is always on the right.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the autoresizing screenshots correctly, the '42' control is behaving as specified. You've pinned the right side of the '42' counter to right side of the cell. And that is where it stays, glued to the right side of the cell.

The cell is pinned to the left side of the tableview and that is where it stays, glued to the left side of the tableview. You have not pinned the right side of the cell to anything and so when you resize, the right side goes where it pleases, only maintaining the specified width of the cell. If you want to glue the right side of the cell to the width of the tableView or column (not sure which it is), pin it. Do specify a minimum width for the cell. If you don't specify a maximum width, or fixed width, the cell will stretch and shrink with resizing. If you fix the width, only the right view or column will stretch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
BTW, even though I have pinned the right side of the cell to right, still the '42" control moves to right after resizing. Also even if I unpinned of '42' which was pinned to right work same way.
I think the Mail app automatically adjust the position of count after launch would be a hint.